# Can't ping default gateway (Gaia, Check Point) from Windows 7 machine in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, ping, checkpoint-firewall

I'm trying to set up a virtual network according to the topology in the CCSM Lab Setup Guide (Check Point training) with the following subset of VMs giving me trouble. All of this is being run in VirtualBox 6.1.22.

**VM Setup**

**1:** Windows 7 (B-GUI-MGMT) VM, 1 ethernet port connected to internal network with ipv4 address of 10.2.2.201 and default gateway address of 10.2.2.1 (I'm below 10 rep so can't embed pictures, otherwise I would attach).

**2:** Check Point Gaia OS (B-GW) VM, 3 ethernet ports, one of which is attached to the same internal network as B-GUI-MGMT with the 1st port (eth0) of ipv4 address 10.2.2.1 (as this is the default gateway). I can ping 10.2.2.201 successfully from this VM but I can't ping 10.2.2.1 *from* 10.2.2.201 in return, not sure why.

**Troubleshooting Tried:**

I've already done a few days worth of troubleshooting and here are some clarifications so it's clear what I've already tried:

MAC addresses for VMs are different

Windows 7 firewall is disabled

Windows 7 ethernet adapter is correctly labeled with 10.2.2.201 as its ipv4 address with 10.2.2.1 as the default gateway

Internal Network in VirtualBox is correctly configured

**Clues**

I've done some digging and think it might have something to do with Windows interpreting a dynamic IP of the gateway, I say this as when I run `arp -a` I get back that 10.2.2.1 is dynamic whilst all other addresses are static. Maybe I need to somehow set up a static IP on the gateway?

It appears to be a problem with the gateway's visibility on the network as I can't ping it from Windows 7 or my Kali Linux on the same network.

Any pointers are a huge help. Thanks guys

Comment: *"I can't ping it from Windows 7 or my Kali Linux on the same network."* - Maybe it's a firewall (or similar issue) on `10.2.2.1` itself? Perhaps it is explicitly blocking `ping` requests from other network devices?

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to think the same, although I can't seem to figure out how to allow requests to come through from gateway side (10.2.2.1). Thanks for the response @Anaksunaman.